# Best way to simulate DOM events for unit tests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using moo4q+jquery, with qUnit+sinon test framework.

Currently to trigger a click event, I have done the following:

`object.jThis.click();  // simulate a click event`

Where `object.jThis` is the jQuery object (wrapper set) the object maps to.

For me the issue is that other events such as `.hover()` do not trigger an event the same way as `.click()`.

Is this just an inconsistency in jQuery's API?

EDIT:

```
// wire up event
attach: function() {
    this.jThis.hover(function(eventObj) {
        this.proxied.showOptionsProxy(true);
    }, function() {
        this.proxied.showOptionsProxy(false);
    });
}
// unit test: 
test("Test_hover_shows_menu", 2, function() {
    var target = this.getTarget();
    this.spy(target.proxied, 'showOptionsProxy');
    target.detach(); // must detach only for unit test after setting up spy on the proxy
    target.attach();
    target.jThis.mouseenter();
    ok(target.proxied.showOptionsProxy.calledWith(true), "hovering over options button shows the menu");
    target.jThis.mouseleave();
    ok(target.proxied.showOptionsProxy.calledWith(false), "mousing away from options button hides menu");
});
```

Comment: Do you want to write an integration test which test the click is fired or a unit test which tests that the code inside the event is doing what it suppose to do? It sounds to me that you are trying to do an integration test.

Comment: I am trying to test that the click event handlers execute, if a click event occurs.  I am trying to do this by "mocking" events.  I don't have a real DOM, just the jQuery DOM, so due to this isolation I would consider it a unit test.  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not so much testing moo tools Event object's ability to wire up event handlers, I'm more less making sure that indeed they were wired up correctly (i.e. no typos in the event string name, and that it wasn't accidentally detached or overridden.)  I think it is a valid test, no?

Comment: In my opinion http://seleniumhq.org/ is the best

Comment: @Bondye, thanks for the link.  Selenium is a tool for a completely different purpose than unit tests though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hover()` is not an event but sugar for `.on( "mouseenter mouseleave")`, you can trigger hover by triggering `.mouseenter()` for the entering phase, and `.mouseleave()` for the leaving phase

See: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLMJ/

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  More generally, is this a good way to trigger events for unit tests?  Using these jQuery APIs?

Comment: @mrjustinmooser yes. Though if your event handlers use things such as mouse coordinates, you need to fake those in the triggered event as well. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for how. Btw, this assumes all event handlers are made with jQuery, jQuery doesn't trigger events bound with dom methods or other libraries.

Comment: I posted my actual code because .mouseenter() .mouseover() doesn't seem to be working.  Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Esailija you are sure that trigger not trigger non-jquery events ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/sjQed/

Comment: I guess I should be more specific and say that the hover event handler isn't even called.  (I inserted a breakpoint in the anonymous event handler for mouseenter and it never get's hit.)

Comment: @eicto there are some exceptions such as  click because jQuery calls the `.click()` method directly on the dom element. Another ones are `submit` and `reset`. For example this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/sjQed/2/

Comment: @mrjustinmooser can you do a sanity check with console logs or alerts, the jsfiddle is as simple as possible and it works, so something else must be broken.

Comment: That's fair enough Esailija.  The event triggering its callbacks is a synchronous operation right?